# Add a new column to a view in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I have a database and I've made a view with the data I want. The data looks something like this:

```
    n     |   value |
----------+---------+
 50404791 |     112 | 
  5034591 |     164 |
 50280287 |      31 |
```

I want to add a column of text like this:

```
    n     |   value | status |
----------+---------+--------+
 50404791 |     112 |default | 
  5034591 |     164 |biggest |
 50280287 |      31 |smallest|
```

I tried `Alter Table Table1 Add Column status text ;` but it seems like text is not a data type. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: `Alter Table Table1 Add status text ;` Can you try this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested on Rextester.com (remember, avoid anyway to use `SELECT *` in a view)

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ID INTEGER);
CREATE VIEW V1 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (0);

ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD COLUMN STATUS TEXT;    
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, STATUS) VALUES (1, 'aaa');

SELECT * FROM V1;
DROP VIEW V1;

CREATE VIEW V1 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
SELECT * FROM V1;
```

Output:

```
    id
1   0
2   1

    id  status
1   0   NULL
2   1   aaa
```

Answer (score 4):

In Postgres you can use `CREATE OR REPLACE` without dropping the view and do the following

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View1 AS
        SELECT value, status FROM Table 1;
```

Altering the original table will just alter that table without changes to the view.

Comment: Just to add extra information to this answer, the new column should be the last one, otherwise, it will throw some errors when executing the query.

Comment: Also this only works for adding new columns to the view. Removing columns requires a drop first.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to drop and re-create the view - you can't alter an existing view. And yes, text IS a data type.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer on `postgresql.org`

> You can do from pgAdmin by right-clicking on the view and select
>   CREATE SCRIPT uncomment:   DROP VIEW ; and edit the CREATE
>   VIEW  to drop the column.
>
> However if the view is used in other views you have to drop them all
>   and recreate in sequence.
>
> Alternatively you can delete the columns from the
>   pg_catalog.pg_attribute table. Make sure however that you know you
>   deleting only the one's you want to delete and not other tables
>   columns... using the below:
>
> delete from pg_attribute where attrelid = regclass 'yourviewname' and
>   attname = 'columnnametodrop'
>
> Best to first do couple of selects until you have the selection
>   correct:
>
> select attrelid::regclass as whatever, * from pg_attribute where
>   attname = 'columnnametodrop'
>
> Johan Nel.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is in pgAdmin, I right click on the view and click on "Scripts" -> "CREATE Script".

This gives me the create/replace structure which I add to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.view_name
 AS
 SELECT a."COLUMN1",
    a."COLUMN2",
    b."COLUMN1",
    b."COLUMN2",
    b."NEWCOLUMN1"
    FROM schema."TABLEA" a
    LEFT JOIN schema."TABLEB b ON a."ID" = b."ID"

ALTER TABLE shcema.view_name
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Add the columns (ex: b."NEWCOLUMN1") and run.  If I have a lot, I'll run a python script to format the columns to paste in.

Always save the original so you can revert!